# There is an error shows "cannot access zzbfm" in map activity in android studio when I am adding UI Firestore dependency in gradle file

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, google-play-services, google-cloud-firestore

My gradle file is as below:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
```

It shows an error while building an APK:

```
cannot access zzbfm class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found
```

But it resolved the error when I remove the Firebase-UI dependency, however I need to use both dependencies in my app.

So what to do?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please update your Play Service dependecy to the latest version like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:16.0.1'
```

More informations [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

And in your top level `build.gradle` file, please don't forget to use the following Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try and let you know. @Alex Mamo

Comment: Ok, that's perfect. Keep me posted.

Comment: hey Alex, i have tried ur solution, it's not working bcoz there is no version 16.0.0 of this play service. Google play service auth, cast and analytics has only this version.

Comment: @SiddharthDholu Hi Siddharth! Please see my updated answer.